# Filter out an object within an object array based on its index (typescript + nextjs)

Tags: typescript, next.js

im trying to filter out the item i want to remove from the list by using its index.

Example: i want to remove item with index 0, id pass the 0 to the filter function to return object at all positions without object at position 0

Here's what i currently have:

```
function removeCartItemHandler(index) {
    console.log(index)
    if (index != -1) {
      cart = cart.splice(index, 1);
      cart.filter(cart[index]);
      setCartItems(cart);
    }
    console.log(cart)
  }
```

Comment: What isn't working about what you have? Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a [mre] that other people can paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue for themselves. Right now my IDE doesn't know what `cart` or `setCartItems` are, and it's also not happy that `index` doesn't have a type annotation (are you using TypeScript or just plain JavaScript?).  If you can make it easy for others to play around with the code, then you increase the chances of getting a useful answer.  If you do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I see you use hooks, general note is to use the modifier func instead of manipulating the original state `cart`.
Something like

```js
function removeCartItemHandler(index) {
    console.log(index)
    if (index != -1) {
      setCartItems(prevItems => prevItems.filter((element, elementIndex) => { return elementIndex !== index  } ));
    }
    console.log(cart)
  }
```